# Bootstrap Button Group with separated buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstraps button group to create a Radio button form, but I don't want the buttons to be grouped together. I need them to all have rounded corners on each corner, and padding between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.radio input[type="radio"]{display:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<div class="radio">
  <label class="btn btn-success"><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="btn btn-success"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="btn btn-success"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

```css
.radio input[type="radio"]{display:none;}
```

Comment: can you hide the radio button?

Answer (score 0):

I just write a basic **Bootstrap Radio Button Group**. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary m-2 rounded active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" checked> Active Option
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary m-2 rounded">
    <input type="radio" name="options"> Option
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary m-2 rounded">
    <input type="radio" name="options"> Option
  </label>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: React has an issue with not closing the Input tags.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you share your complete code on https://stackblitz.com. Thanks